# Jboss Form Auth fails when using utf8 characters

Tags: authentication, encoding, utf-8, jboss, ldap

I am using both Jboss 7.1.1 and Wildfly10

for my application, I am using authentication by LDAP

And I have issue with utf-8 accents in password

for example, username with password contained "é" can not login to the application with Wildfly10, I found a solution here

[Wildfly Form Auth fails when using special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37699579/wildfly-form-auth-fails-when-using-special-characters)

But I can not find the same config for Jboss.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with | and {} characters in POST URL,

There is a way to allow these characters in URL, set ALLOW_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS_IN_URL=true in your startup script.

./bin/standalone.sh -Dorg.wildfly.undertow.ALLOW_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS_IN_URL=true

visit Jboss forum for more, https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-13710